# Pandas does not recognise a column of floats when importing a csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the IMF statistics into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2013/02/weodata/WEOOct2013all.xls",
                   na_values=['n/a','--'],thousands=',')
```

All the columns, except one, have dtype object:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8318 entries, 0 to 8317
Data columns (total 49 columns):
...
dtypes: float64(1), object(48)
```

I manually inspected the file and could not find any value which is not a numeric one, or one of the NaN values explicitly mentioned in the code, in most columns.

*I am using Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.1, pandas 0.11.0 on Anaconda 1.5.0 on Wakari.io.*

Comment: Try writing code that iterates over the values in each column and calls `float` on each, and see where/if an exception is raised.

Comment: I can't, because the values have thousand separators. read_table should remove them (argument thousands of the function)

Comment: Okay, then write code that removes the thousands separators and then calls `float`.  Alternatively, trim down your data file gradually until it starts working, then zero in on the difference that made it stop working.

Comment: IIRC this is a bug that was fixed in 0.12...though can't remember the ref ATM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by Jeff, this was [a bug in <=0.12](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322) (but is fixed in 0.13).

```
In [11]: s = '''A;B
1;2,000
3;4'''

In [12]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=';', thousands=',')
Out[12]: 
   A     B
0  1  2000
1  3     4

[2 rows x 2 columns]

In [13]: pd.version.version
Out[13]: '0.13.0rc1-82-g66934c2'
```